# My registrar is OVH, my hosting is AlwaysData, how do I configure the DNS?

Tags: subdomain, cname-record

I own at OVH:

```
xxx.mydomain.com
```

I want it as an alias for:

```
yyy.alwaysdata.net
```

How do I proceed?

In the end, I want all requests to :

```
xxx.mydomain.com/whatever
```

returning the same as:

```
yyy.alwaysdata.net/whatever
```

without any url rewriting in the browser.

I have tried to add xxx.mydomain.com CNAME to yyy.alwaysdata.net on OVH with no success.

Should I do anything on the AlwaysData side?

### Edit (updated)

The result of the command `host` is:

```
host xxx.mydomain.com
xxx.mydomain.com is an alias for yyy.alwaysdata.net.
yyy.alwaysdata.net has address 178.32.28.117
```

The result of the command `nslookup` is:

```
nslookup xxx.mydomain.com
Server:     192.168.178.1
Address:    192.168.178.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
xxx.mydomain.com    canonical name = yyy.alwaysdata.net.
Name:   yyy.alwaysdata.net
Address: 178.32.28.117
```

So strangely enough, a new IP address has shown up, 178.32.28.117:

```
nslookup 178.32.28.117
Server:     192.168.178.1
Address:    192.168.178.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
117.28.32.178.in-addr.arpa  name = http7.alwaysdata.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

Right now, when I go to xxx.mydomain.com I have http://http7.alwaysdata.com/ in place of yyy.alwaysdata.net

Comment: What does 'no success' mean? Did you check if the CNAME is resolved after setting it? What does `host` or `nslookup` say when you try to resolve `xxx.mydomain.com`?

Comment: I've added the information by edit my post. 'no success' means Chrome give me a 204 and curl give me a `no route to host`.

Comment: Why did you point your CNAME to `dns1.alwaysdata.com`? Is this the domain you want it to point to?

Comment: It was a refresh problem, please see updated info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [administration page](https://admin.alwaysdata.com/) of alwaysdata, go to *Sites* then edit your site properties. You can here add addresses that match your site. Just add `xxx.mydomain.com` as a new address and save.

[image: Alwaysdata site settings]

Comment: It works the way I wanted, thanks! Further explanations much appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

The method for you to do that thing is `Inline Redirect`. You can do that by register this service with your registrar OVH.

[This](http://www.networking4all.com/en/support/domain+names/domain+redirects/) will have you.

Comment: I made an invisible ORT redirect (see http://help.ovh.co.uk/DomainServicesManager). It added a Type A field in my DNS settings:
`xxx.mydomain.com A 213.186.33.5`
Does not seem to be what I am looking for.

Comment: Do you own `yyy.alwaysdata.net`? I think invisible ORT redirect would solve your problem. You should remove the CNAME for `xxx.mydomain.com`, update DNS and try again.

Comment: I do not own yyy.alwaysdata.net, it belongs to AlwaysData. If ORT redirect is an iframe, it's not solving my problem.

Comment: So you couldn't use CNAME. As you say `without any url rewriting in the browser`, I think it must be solved. Maybe some problems from OVH invisible ORT redirect, please try to contact OVH and ask about your problem.